# Set Default Shipping Price in Cart When Customer Isn't Signed In

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, sales-quote

I am trying to set up Magento so that if a new customer that isn't signed in and they add a product to their cart, it has a pre-selected shipping method and shows the price for that shipping method, in addition to the total being updated. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This module sounds like what you need:
https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping